# R- How to save the console data into a row/matrix or data frame for future use?

Tags: r

I'm performing the multiple regression to find the best model to predict the prices. See as following for the output in the R console.

I'd like to store the first column (Estimates) into a row/matrix or data frame for future use such as using R shiny to deploy on the web.

***(Price = 698.8+0.116*voltage-70.72*VendorCHICONY
-36.6*VendorDELTA-66.8*VendorLITEON-14.86*H)***

Can somebody kindly advise?? Thanks in advance.

```
  Call:
  lm(formula = Price ~ Voltage + Vendor + H, data = PSU2)

  Residuals:
  Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
  -10.9950  -0.6251   0.0000   3.0134  11.0360 

  Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
  (Intercept)   698.821309 276.240098   2.530   0.0280 *  
  Voltage         0.116958   0.005126  22.818 1.29e-10 ***
  VendorCHICONY -70.721088   9.308563  -7.597 1.06e-05 ***
  VendorDELTA   -36.639685   5.866688  -6.245 6.30e-05 ***
  VendorLITEON  -66.796531   6.120925 -10.913 3.07e-07 ***
  H             -14.869478   6.897259  -2.156   0.0541 .  
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

  Residual standard error: 7.307 on 11 degrees of freedom
  Multiple R-squared:  0.9861,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9799 
  F-statistic: 156.6 on 5 and 11 DF,  p-value: 7.766e-10
```

Comment: [broom](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom) might be useful

Comment: Thanks for the reply first, but I cannot understand. Would you explain more detailed? Thanks.

Comment: `coef(model)` will give you estimates. If you save a model (using `save`) into .RData object, you can later import it and use `predict` to predict prices based on your values.

Comment: @Samotht Install `broom` using `install.packages`. Then use `broom::tidy(my_model)`. It handles most common model types and returns a nice `data.frame` with consistent column names.

Comment: thanks @Nick K and hrbrmstr, using broom is an easy way save as data frame, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coef` on your `lm` output.

e.g.

```
m <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, iris)
summary(m)

# Call:
# lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)

# Residuals:
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -1.30711 -0.25713 -0.05325  0.19542  1.41253 
# 
# Coefficients:
#                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)         2.2514     0.3698   6.089 9.57e-09 ***
# Sepal.Width         0.8036     0.1063   7.557 4.19e-12 ***
# Speciesversicolor   1.4587     0.1121  13.012  < 2e-16 ***
# Speciesvirginica    1.9468     0.1000  19.465  < 2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.438 on 146 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.7259,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7203 
# F-statistic: 128.9 on 3 and 146 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

coef(m)
#       (Intercept)       Sepal.Width Speciesversicolor  Speciesvirginica 
#         2.2513932         0.8035609         1.4587431         1.9468166
```

See also `names(m)` which shows you some things you can extract, e.g. `m$residuals` (or equivalently, `resid(m)`).

And also `methods(class='lm')` will show you some other functions that work on a lm.

```
> methods(class='lm')
 [1] add1           alias          anova          case.names     coerce         confint        cooks.distance deviance       dfbeta         dfbetas        drop1          dummy.coef     effects        extractAIC     family        
[16] formula        hatvalues      influence      initialize     kappa          labels         logLik         model.frame    model.matrix   nobs           plot           predict        print          proj           qr            
[31] residuals      rstandard      rstudent       show           simulate       slotsFromS3    summary        variable.names vcov
```

(oddly, 'coef' is not in there? ah well)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! However,  I'd strongly recommend using package "broom", which nicely stores the data as data frame type for an easy use.

Answer (score 0):

Besides, I'd like to know if there is command to show the "residual percentage"
=(actual value-fitted value)/actual value"; currently the "residuals()" command can 
only show the below info but I need the percentage instead.

```
residuals(fit3ab)
 1             2             3             4             5             6      
-5.625491e-01 -5.625491e-01  7.676578e-15 -8.293815e+00 -5.646900e+00  3.443652e+00
```